# Probability of an item being picked in a weight based system that picks 3 unique items

Tags: probability

I'm attempting to calculate the probability of each item in a set being picked based on what its weight is (i.e a weight of $2$ is twice as likely as a weight of $1$, etc). However, it's not just one item being picked, it's $3$ at a time, and they must be unique (the same item cannot be picked multiple times).

The basic formula for just one item would be $$P_x = \frac{\text{weight}}{ \text{sum of weights}}$$. The first thing that I thought of was just tripling the probability, but that doesn't seem like it would be very accurate. For example, tripling a $35\%$ chance would give a $105\%$ chance, but an item can't have a chance of getting picked that's higher than $100\%$... and besides that, there would be about a $27\%$ chance that it wouldn't get picked.

The next thing I thought of was $$P_x = 1 - \left( 1 -  \frac{\text{weight}}{ \text{sum of weights}}\right)^3$$
However, that seems to underestimate the probabilities by a fair bit (for example, at $27$ items with weight $1$, I would be expecting the sum of the probabilities to be $300\%$, but they're only $289.03\%$). After that I tried a formula that is slightly more complicated:
$$ P_x = 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{\text{weight}}{\text{sum}} \right) \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{\text{weight}}{\text{sum - average}} \right) \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{\text{weight}}{\text{sum} - 2 \cdot \text{average}} \right) $$
(with $\text{sum}$ and $\text{average}$ being the sum and average of all weights in the set respectively)

And while it does seem to be better (a set of items with the same weight will add up to $300\%$, and for a more complex set I am getting $297.04\%$ instead of $286.66\%$), it isn't perfect. If the weight of one item is significantly higher than the rest, then it will be way off on the items with the lower probability. For example, in a set with weights of $2 \text{X}  10,000$ and $3 \text{X} 1$, you'd expect the two with $10,000$ to have basically a $100\%$ chance of getting picked and the remaining ones to have a roughly $33\%$ chance, however, instead, you get $96.87\%$ and $0.02\%$ (adding up to a total of $193.80\%$).

I did try a few other formulas that I could think of, however, they all seemed to be *worse* than the one above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but can't you just express the probability that a fixed item $x$ is picked up as a sum $T_1 + T_2 + T_2$, where $T_i$ calculates the probability that $x$ was the $i$th item that was picked up?

Comment: I tried to do something like that but it ended up being even less accurate... however it's not unlikely for that to be due to me messing up the formula in some way. The way I wrote it, it's a huge mess.

Comment: Well, I tried to rewrite the formula in a way that doesn't make it a complete mess, and it seems to be just marginally better than the one in the original post.
Essentially it is: $(weight / sum) + (1 - weight / sum) * (weight / (sum - average\;of\;others)) + (1 - weight / sum) * (1 - (1 - weight / sum) * (weight / (sum - average\;of\;others))) * (weight / (sum - 2 * average\;of\;others))$
($average\;of\;others$ is the average weight of all other items)
...Yeah it's still kind of a mess imo, but better than what it used to be.